# C++ circular list error

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I am creating a program that will take a list of n items and then eliminate every third item until there is only 1 left. I am getting an error where my code is accessing a list item that does not exist. I know I can modify this using an integer counter but I would prefer to get to the root of the problem

```
int main()
{
    double suitors=0;
    int checker=0;
    int temp=0;
    do
    {
        cout << "How many suitors are there, min of 4 \n";
        cin >> suitors ;
        checker=suitors;
        if (cin.fail()||checker!=suitors||suitors<4)
        {
            cout << "You have entered an invalid input.\n";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(100, '\n');
            suitors=-1;
        }
    }
    while (checker!=suitors||suitors<4);
    list<int> men;  

    for (int j=1; j<=suitors; j++)
    {
        men.push_back(j);
    }
    list<int>::iterator i;
    i=men.begin();

    for (int j=1; j<suitors;j++)
    {
        temp=0;
        while (temp<3)
        {
            temp=temp+1;
            if (temp==3)
            {
                cout << "Suitor #" << *i << " is eliminated \n";
                i=men.erase(i);
                break;
            }
            if (i!=men.end())
            {
                i++;
            }
            else //this is trying to reset the iterator to the start when it hits the end
            {
                i=men.begin();
            }
        }
    }
    i=men.begin();
    cout << "If there are " << suitors 
    << " then the winner will be suitors #" << *i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This part is the bug:

```
if (i!=men.end())
{
    i++;
}
else //this is trying to reset the iterator to the start when it hits the end
{
    i=men.begin();
}
```

If `i` points to the last item of the list, it will take the `i != men.end()` route, execute `++i`, and then `i == men.end()` on the next trip through the loop.

The proper code is:

```
if(i == men.end())
    i = men.begin();
if(++i == men.end())
    i = men.begin();
```

Comment: I think the third line should begin with else; `else if(++i ...`

Comment: It could, but I chose to refrain from optimizing because, optimally, this entire algorithm shouldn't be used in the first place.

Comment: Thanks mike and wimmel, I implemented your changes and one small change to my counting and it worked perfectly

Comment: @MikeDeSimone if `i == men.end()` you will execute `i = men.begin()` followed by `++i`.